# Media with WYSIWYG not converting media tags to markup

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

I just installed the Media module v 7.x-2.0-alpha3 along with WYSIWYG, CKEditor, and Image Resize Filter. (The site has many other modules active.)  The site also uses Display Suite, and its view modes are used for different types of images. My use case is for images embedded in the Filtered HTML text format, not as separate entities in a content type.

When an image is first embedded, its source code is like this:

```
[[{"fid":"161","view_mode":"default","fields":{"format":"default","field_file_image_alt_text[und][0][value]":"f asdfasdf"},"type":"media","attributes":{"alt":"alt text","class":"media-element file-default"}}]]
```

From my reading, I found that checking "Convert Media tags to markup" at mysite/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html is required. I have verified that is active.

Instructions at https://www.drupal.org/node/1599070 include *"Image resize filter" is AFTER "Convert Media tags to markup"* and my filters are in that order.

If I double-click an embedded image in the CKEditor and make it a captioned image, then the Media tags are converted to markup. If a caption isn't added, the Media tags do not get converted.

Based on my configuration, can anyone suggest why the conversion is not occurring?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have any solution for that problem now?

Comment: I too have the same issue and its driving me mad.

Comment: schulle877, I have not found a solution for this yet.

Comment: The image resize filter should be after media tags for markup. Check that the filter is allowing images tags also.

Comment: Just in case that you have done anything and it still does not working: make sure that all double quotes (`"`) are properly opened and closed in the node's body field, otherwise you wiil get unrendered items (`[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_original","fid":"995"}}]]`). Perhaps this a media's module bug!

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same problem and have solved it. My problem was not rendering the text in the correct format in the template. So if you are using a custom theme, .tpl or whatever you need to make sure you render it correctly. I had it like this:

```
<?php print $node->field_main_body['und'][0]['value'] ;?>
```

Changing this to proper rendering using `field_view_field` fixed it for me:

```
<?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_main_body', array('label'=>'hidden'))) ;?>
```

Hope that's helpful

Comment: In my case, this was the cause. I was printing the value instead of the rendered markup.

Comment: I'd upvote a thousand times more if I could. Wow what a pain it was to figure this out. I even asked in another thread like half a year ago and got no response. You'd think with all the minds behind drupal you wouldn't need some special way to render to handle media tags... in this day and age. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking that your "Limit html tags" isnt limiting your img tags

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I need to have 50 rep points to comment on a post? How do you suggest i leave comments/ request more info, without answering, if i cant comment ?

Comment: The list of allowed HTML tags does allow img tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you updated Media, WYSIWYG and CTools module with latest stable version, then run update.php The embeded image source code will automatically convert to image.