# Convert Media tags to markup failing again

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

Once again I am plagued by this. Embedding an image from the media library shows in the editor, but when you view the node on the front end you get this:

```
[[{"fid":"851","view_mode":"default","fields":{"format":"default","field_file_image_alt_text[und][0][value]":"Reality Check","field_file_image_title_text[und][0][value]":""},"type":"media","attributes":{"height":"333","width":"1502","style":"font-size: 13.008px;","class":"media-element file-default"}}]]
```

Normally you would confirm a couple things in drupal 7.5 -

- Check the text format configuration to make sure convert media tags
  to markup is set. In my case its on every filter and it is in the top
  position. no matter which position it is in, still nothing works.
- Check to see if a custom template is used and make sure it's using
  render() and not just a plain echo. In my case, it is a custom
  template and it is using `render($node->body['und'][0]['value'])`
- Check to see if any wrapping tags may be causing a conflict. In my
  case there is no wrapping tag. It's just an inline image from the
  media library.

I'm using a custom tinyMCE install with the wysiwyg module because for reasons unknown the media library module broke everything much worse. Somehow I don't think this has anything to do with tinyMCE though.

Anyone have any further ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of us just constantly plagued by this failure in programming, here's a link with the solution that worked for me. Upvote if you find it helpful:
[Media with WYSIWYG not converting media tags to markup](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120056/media-with-wysiwyg-not-converting-media-tags-to-markup)

Essentially, don't trust `print render()` - I had to use this in my custom template file:

```
<?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'body', array('label'=>'hidden'))) ;?>
```